# Undefined control sequence when using graphics

Tags: graphics, undefined

I get an error message, whenever I am trying to use graphics. 
I have MikTex 2.9 installed on my Windows and checked that the graphics package is downloaded and updated several times. I even reinstalled it.

This is what I coded:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphics}   %%<--Without this line it runs perfectly fine. 

\begin{document}
blablabla
\end{document}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ifpdf
\let \pdftexcmds@temp \ltx@one \@PackageInfoNoLine {pdftex...
l.440 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext) [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext) \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
! Extra \fi.
\@begindocumenthook ...}[2009/07/12]\fi }{} }}\fi
\global \let \bibstyle =\@...
l.17 \begin{document}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
[1
{C:/Users/Lara/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(SP1_report.toc)
\tf@toc=\write3
\openout3 = `SP1_report.toc'.
[1] [1] [2]
```

The Warning regarding the bibstyle does also not appear without trying to use graphics.. 
What can I try to solve the problem? If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: check for updates in the miktex console in user **and** admin mode. Update also the package database (in the menu task).

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't updated in admin mode. Now it works! 
But one more Question: In the miktex console it only shows the graphics package, which still does not work. But graphicx works now, which is not included in the packages-list. How do I understand this?

Comment: graphicx is in graphics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was solved by updating the system in the proper mode, as noted in the comments.